# Meteor.renderList alway end up in [elseFunc]

Tags: meteor

I'm new to Meteor.

Trying to render items from collection but Meteor.renderList(observable, docFunc, [elseFunc]) alway go to elseFunc.

```
this.ComponentViewOrdersFlow = Backbone.View.extend({
  template: null,
  initialize: function() {
    var frag;
    Template.ordersFlow.events = {
      "click a": function(e) {
        return App.router.aReplace(e);
      }
    };
    this.template = Meteor.render(function() {
      return Template.ordersFlow();
    });
    console.log(Colors);
    frag = Meteor.renderList(
        Colors.find(),
        function(color) {
            console.log(color);
        },
        function() {
         console.log('else consdition');
        }
    );
  },
  render: function() {
    this.$el.html(this.template);
    return this;
  }
});
```

Initially I thought that Collection is empty, but console.log(Colors) shows that there are items in collection. Moreover if I use Meteor.render(... -> Template.colors({colors: Colors.find()}) ) it renders template end show Collection items there.

Meteor version 0.6.6.3 (Windows 7, 64bit)
Mongo - connected to MongoLab

Thank you for any help.
Jev.

Comment: Are you sure you need to use Backbone? I ask because it complicates tasks like this that are quite simple with Meteor's template engine. Also, you are using an outdated version of Meteor - the current version is 0.7.0.1

Comment: Well even if Backbone complicates it, still it should not have impact on Meteor.renderList(). I see no any other way how to nicely structure Mateor App, this is why I went for Backbone.

Comment: If you use Meteor's template engine, you really never need to call `Meteor.render()` or `Meteor.renderList()`. You can simply put in your parent template `{{#each colors}}{{> color}}{{/each}}`. Meteor's template engine can be used to replace Backbone's view and events systems and the `iron-router` package is a great router built specifically for Meteor. Backbone's collections seem somewhat incompatible with Meteor's, and Backbone's models can be replaced with a system like Meteor's `simple-schema` package.

Comment: Hmmm, Meteor documentation states that without render() I will not archive reactivity, which is the main reason of using Meteor.

Comment: Unfortunately I am unable to repro this issue on either 0.6.6.3 or 0.7.0.1. Is it possible your DB has been reset at some point? If you replace your `elseFunc` definition with `console.log(Colors.find().fetch().length)` what does it log?

Comment: Meteor's templates are automatically called with `render()` and `renderList()`. They achieve reactivity automatically. Those are low-level functions that you don't need to worry about when using Meteor's  handlebars template system. Look at the [leaderboard example](https://www.meteor.com/examples/leaderboard) - it is reactive, but it does not contain a single call to `render()` or `renderList()`. When you place a template in the special `<body>` template, it will be reactively rendered with no extra work on your part.

Comment: From the Meteor Docs under `Meteor.render()` - "Most Meteor apps don't need to call this directly; they use templates and Meteor handles the rendering." - and under `Meteor.renderList()` - "Most Meteor apps use {{#each}} in a template instead of calling this directly."

Comment: console.log(Colors.find().fetch().length) returns 0.
Ok, seems like there is issue with accessing collection data. Thank you for pointing in to this, will do some more debugging.

Comment: Yes, so somehow your database no longer contains any colors. Perhaps you restarted the development server? But please go look at the source code for the leaderboard example. You will be surprised how simple this is when you let handlebars call the `render` and `renderList` functions for you ;)

Comment: From Meteor doc..renderList is more efficient than using Meteor.render to render HTML for a list of documents. For example, if a new document is created in the database that matches the query, a new item will be rendered and inserted at the appropriate place in the DOM without re-rendering the other elements. Similarly, if a document changes position in a sorted query, the DOM nodes will simply be moved and not re-rendered...I do not want all collection items to be re-rendered every time query result changes.Using {{#each colors}}{{> color}}{{/each}} with render will re-render all items,right?

Comment: From the Meteor Docs, regarding `renderList`: **"Most Meteor apps use {{#each}} in a template instead of calling this directly."** - You don't need to use either of those methods. They are low level functions that are automatically handled by Meteor's handlebars template engine. When you make a handlebars template, Meteor *automatically* calls `render` or `renderList` on it. Please, go look at the [leaderboard example](https://www.meteor.com/examples/leaderboard). It shows how to make a Meteor app the Meteor way - handlebars templates, and allowing Meteor to call `render` automatically.

Comment: Man, thanks a lot for help. Will check leaderboard example.

Answer (score 0):

Can't really explain this well in the comments, so here is a very, very simple example of using the Meteor template engine. This is a 100% functional app, showcasing basic reactivity. Note that I *never* call `render()` or `renderList()` anywhere.

All this app does is show a button, that when clicked, adds a number to a list. The number is reactively added to the list, even though I never do anything to make that reactivity explicit. Meteor's templates are automatically reactive! Try it out - this is all of the code.

numbers.html:

```html
<body>
  {{> numberList}}
</body>

<template name="numberList">
  <ul>
    {{#each numbers}}
    <li>{{number}}</li>
    {{/each}}
  </ul>
  <button>Click Me</button>
</template>
```

numbers.js:

```js
var Numbers = new Meteor.Collection("numbers");

if (Meteor.isClient) {
  Template.numberList.numbers = function() {
    return Numbers.find();
  };

  var idx = 0;
  Template.numberList.events({
    "click button": function() {
      Numbers.insert({
        number: idx
      });
      idx++;
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: can this <li>{{number}}</li> be a separate template with own reactive data ?

Comment: @JevgenijsGolojads Yes, just replace it with `{{> number}}` and add a template like `<template name="number"><li>{{number}}</li></template>`

Comment: Thanks dude, and Happy New Year